# Who has a functional build.properties file for building Eclipse 3.5M6 under OS X?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I want to take a stab at tinkering with an Eclipse standard functionality so I would like to build Eclipse under OS X 10.5.  I have downloaded the source bundle, unpacked it, and found that I need to fill out a build.properties file which I have done like (with Java 6 as the default JVM)

```
J2SE-1.4=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4/
J2SE-1.5=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/
JavaSE-1.6=/Library/Java/Home/
```

and then invoke it with

```
./build -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86
```

which builds the ecj.jar and invokes ant which then fails with thousands of error messages from the javac task.  The most telling is

```
    [javac] The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

as it to me clearly indicates that the appropriate libraries are not correctly picked up.

Is there anybody who can help with a functional build.properties file for OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These properties need to specify the actual boot classpath to use for that environment.  It is not enough to point at the root of the jre, you need to list the actual *.jar files.

example:

```
J2SE-1.5=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Classes/classes.jar:\
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Classes/jsse.jar:\
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Classes/charsets.jar
```